# How we can rebuild the widget during run time on button click?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have created the dynamic widgets which shows checkboxes but it only updates when we load the page. I want to update it on every button click. I want when the user answers the questions it should update on button click. I also added show and hide feature on button.

**Below method fetch the data :**

```
var listArray = '';

fetchPalete() async {
    String questionURL = "URL to fetch dat";

    Uri questionURI = Uri.parse(questionURL);
 
    final response = await http.get(questionURI);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      listArray = '';
      String receivedJson = response.body;
      List<dynamic> list = json.decode(receivedJson);
      var questLength = json.decode(response.body);
      lengthofQuestions = questLength.length;
   
      for (int j = 0; j < lengthofQuestions; j++) {
        listArray = listArray + ' ' + list[j]['QuestionStatus'];
      }

    }
  }
```

**this method creates the checkboxes**

```
Widget _buildCheckBoxes() {
  
    if (lengthofQuestions != 0) {
      var qnum = 1;
      Widget? cb;
      for (int i = 1; i <= lengthofQuestions; i++) {
        var b = (listArray.split(' '));
        var sss = b[i];
        if (sss == "Yellow") {
          cb = RichText(
            text: TextSpan(
              children: [
                const WidgetSpan(
                  child: Icon(Icons.check_box_outline_blank,
                      size: 20, color: Colors.yellow),
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: i.toString(),
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.yellow),
                  recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                    ..onTap = () => gotoQuestionByPallete(i),
                ),
              ],
              style:
                  const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, backgroundColor: Colors.white),
              recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                ..onTap = () => gotoQuestionByPallete(i),
            ),
          );
        } else if (sss == "Red") {

          cb = RichText(
            text: TextSpan(
              children: [
                const WidgetSpan(
                  child: Icon(Icons.check_box_outline_blank,
                      size: 20, color: Colors.red),
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: i.toString(),
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.red),
                  recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                    ..onTap = () => gotoQuestionByPallete(i),
                ),
              ],
              style:
                  const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, backgroundColor: Colors.white),
              recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                ..onTap = () => gotoQuestionByPallete(i),
            ),
          );
        } else {

          cb = RichText(
            text: TextSpan(
              children: [
                const WidgetSpan(
                  child: Icon(Icons.check_box, size: 20, color: Colors.green),
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: i.toString(),
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.green),
                  recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                    ..onTap = () => gotoQuestionByPallete(i),
                ),
              ],
              style:
                  const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, backgroundColor: Colors.white),
            ),
          );
        }
        qnum = qnum + 1;
        listcheckbox.add(cb);
      }
    }

    return Wrap(
        direction: Axis.horizontal,
        alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
        spacing: 2,
        children: listcheckbox);

  }
```

Comment: could you add your full code? where is this button, which widget do you want to update ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use setState to update state

Don't use static value. Instead of it, use variable and assign this value to it and update this value of variable by assigning new value with set state to update the state of any widget you want .. e.g. String name = "MyName"; and you have a text widget like this Text (name) and widget button with on pressed function to use to update name value .. on presses(){name="My_Name"; // use set state here and the text widget will change to be My_Name form MyName}

Comment: I have tried the same but its not updating.   Visibility( visible: true,
        maintainState: false,
                  maintainAnimation: false,
                  child: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 5, 5, 5),
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      child: _buildCheckBoxes()
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

Comment: I updated my answer with more details

Comment: this widget has feature to be scrolled its dynamic. and on clicking on number it will do operation

Comment: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _buildCheckBoxes();
                  },
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    primary:
                    Colors.green, 
                  ),
                  child: const Text("Checkbox"),
                ),    This button needed to be clicked